# Oracle Error ORA-28805: Cannot retrieve information from the data source When Calling UTL_HTTP.request

Tags: oracle, api, https, certificate, oracle12c

I am trying to call a web service using the Oracle `UTL_HTTP.request` API. The call requires a proxy & wallet/certificate. I am getting an `ORA-28805: Cannot retrieve information from the data source` error. I am using DBMS version 12.1.0.2.0, and Database PSU 12.1.0.2.160419.

The following **https** call throws the ORA-28805 error:

```
DECLARE
  l_http_request utl_http.req;
  l_http_response utl_http.resp;
  l_text VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  utl_http.set_proxy('myproxy.url.com');
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:/my/wallet/location'
                      ,'mypass');
  -- HTTPS Request --
  l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('https://app.myurl.com/myservice/','GET','HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', 'Token mytoken');
  l_http_response := utl_http.get_response(l_http_request);
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      utl_http.read_text(l_http_response, l_text, 32766);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_text);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
    utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
  END;
END;
```

Runtime exception stack:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-28805: Cannot retrieve information from the data source.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 368
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1118
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

The following **http** call works perfectly & returns a JSON payload:

```
DECLARE
  l_http_request utl_http.req;
  l_http_response utl_http.resp;
  l_text VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  utl_http.set_proxy('myproxy.url.com');
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:/my/wallet/location'
                      ,'mypass');
  -- HTTP request --
  l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1','GET','HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', 'Token mytoken');
  l_http_response := utl_http.get_response(l_http_request);
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      utl_http.read_text(l_http_response, l_text, 32766);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_text);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
    utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
  END;
END;
```

Response:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

I ran the following as system successfully, but it didn't resolve the problem:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_WALLET_ACE
  (
    WALLET_PATH => 'file:/my/wallet/location',
    ACE => XS$ACE_TYPE(
                        PRIVILEGE_LIST => XS$NAME_LIST('use_client_certificates','use_passwords'),
                        PRINCIPAL_NAME => 'myuser',
                        PRINCIPAL_TYPE => XS_ACL.PTYPE_DB
                      )
  );
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error while configuring ACL for wallet: '|| SQLERRM);
END;
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Comment: we are getting similar error : ORA-28782. We also think it has to do with ACL to wallet as documented here : https://ilmarkerm.eu/blog/2012/06/using-ssl-client-certificates-for-authentication-in-utl_http/   : The network ACL needs also privileges on the Wallet file using DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_WALLET_ACL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using both privileges

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/fine_grained_access.htm#DBSEG118

The docs says : Be aware that for wallets, you must specify either the use_client_certificates **OR** use_passwords privileges.